# How to extend cactiverecord

Tags: yii, model, extends

I want add aditional methods in CActiveRecord, but if `class Project_Model extends CActiveRecord {}` get error

> The table "Project_ActiveRecord" for active record class "Project_ActiveRecord" cannot be found in the database.

I want create simple structure: CActiveRecord->Project_ActiveRecord (only extend methods)->Table (real table).

How can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: You don't have a table named `Project_ActiveRecord` in your DB!

If `Project_Model` is going to be the base model for your others active record models then you should do something like:

```
//A base classe example that has a behavior shared by all the inherited class
abstract class Project_Model extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors(){
        return array(
            'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
                'setUpdateOnCreate' => true
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

And then you can declare the other class that **will have a table in the db**:

```
class YourClass extends Project_Model
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Token the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'YourClassTable';
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you **shoudl never call the class `Project_Model`** (this is why I put the keyword `abstract`) in your code, you have to call the inherited classes that **have an existing table** in the db!